# Как получить определенное кол-во строк до необходимой выборки?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть отсортированная выборка данных. Из этой выборки необходимо получить данные, которые соответствуют определенному условию (WHERE) + 5 записей (или другое число), идущих перед выборкой. Т.е. перед первым значением, соответствующем условию. Эти 5 записей необязательно должны соответствовать условию.

Пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить значения больше или равно 9. +5 строк идущих перед первым совпадением. Ответ должен быть следующим: 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 14, 17.
Как это можно реализовать в postgresql или mysql?

Comment: Взять выборку со значениями меньше 9, выполнить обратную сортировку, и отобрать 5 первых строк.

Comment: Ответ должен быть следующим: 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 14, 17, это не больше или равно 9.

Answer (score 0):

Используй  LIMIT и OFFSET.
LIMIT ограничение количества строк.

То есть ты делаешь Select из таблицы с условием что меньше 9, упорядочивает на уменьшение и ставишь LIMIT 5. Получишь 5 строк до 9 ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 7). 
Второй Select из таблицы с условием, что больше или равно 9, упорядочивает на увеличение и ставишь LIMIT 5. Получишь 4 строк после 9 (9, 11, 14, 17) 
 Объединяешь их с помощью union и готово  
 
With as 
 s1 ( select ... <9 order by desc Limit 5), 
s2 as ( select ... >=9 order by  Limit 5) 
 select * from s1 
 union   
select * from s2